# How to fake DateTime in a phpunit test?

Tags: phpunit, symfony4, php-7.2

ssI write a unittest using Symfony's KernelTestCase and have to test for a functionality, which happens only at a certain tie of the day (extra early or extra late).

So when I let my test run a noon of course nothing happens. How can I fake my system time to pretend that it has a different time and my test case is triggered.

I tried around with Symfony's ClockMock class but it does not work. 
https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/phpunit_bridge.html#clock-mocking

This is my test code:

```
use Symfony\Bridge\PhpUnit\ClockMock;
use \DateTime;

/**
 * testUserAchievedEarlyBirdTrophy
 * @group time-sensitive
 */
public function testUserAchievedEarlyBirdTrophy()
{
    ClockMock::withClockMock(strtotime('2018-11-05 01:00:00'));
    echo (new DateTime())->format('Y-m-d H:m:s');

    $user8Id = $this->user8->getId();
    $progressSaveRequest = new ProgressSaveRequest($user8Id, $this->content_1_1->getId());

    $this->progressService->saveProgress($progressSaveRequest);

    $this->assertTrue($this->loggerCreator->hasDebugThatContains(
        'Early Bird'
    ));
}
```

the echo give me today's date: 2019-02-01 16:02:06

I also had the feeling that ClockMock is rather used to skip time for e.g. testing caching instead of sleep().

What am I doing wrong?

The listener configuration is in place in my  phpunit.xml
Calling bin/simple-phpunit causes a lot of installation happening.

Can't I use the normal phpunit?

Are there any other options to fake the time of the day?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following the link you included in your post, the first paragraph says:

> The ClockMock class provided by this bridge allows you to mock the
>   PHP's built-in time functions time(), microtime(), sleep() and
>   usleep(). Additionally the function date() is mocked so it uses the
>   mocked time if no timestamp is specified. **Other functions with an
>   optional timestamp parameter that defaults to time() will still use
>   the system time instead of the mocked time**.
>   (Emphasis added.)

This means that your call of

```
echo (new DateTime())->format('Y-m-d H:m:s');
```

is expected to give the system time, not the mocked time.

Change it to

```
echo date('Y-m-d H:m:s');
```

in order to match the requirements of ClockMock and get the mocked time.

Note: I've never used ClockMock myself, but just looking at the documentation this should be a first step to see if this resolves your problem.

Comment: Great! That was the hint I needed. 

I initialize my DateTime object now with the date() method in the constructor of the method I want to test and it works!
        $myDate =  (new DateTime(date('Y-m-d H:m:s')));